# How to Search Phone number in Address book?

Tags: vba, outlook

There are options to get a contact detail from Mail id or Contact's Name using

```
Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve
```

Is there any option to perform a direct search on Outlook Addressbook with Phone number or Company name etc.?

I am able to get many VBA coding options to loop through each contact in addressbook & find matching contact for phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function. It should return the account name, searching by a phone number.

I played some minutes with my Outlook settings, because it used to not return any Address Book, even if it has a custom one from where it suggests the accounts address when start typing in the `To` box. If a similar problem in your case, I will try explaining what I did. But you maybe are luckier:

```
Function nameByPhoneNo(strPhNo As String) As String
 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim olGAL As Outlook.AddressList, olAdLs As Outlook.AddressLists
 Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntries, olMember As Outlook.AddressEntry

 Set olApp = Outlook.Application
 Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set olAdLs = olNS.AddressLists

 Set olGAL = olAdLs.item(1) 'Your "Contacts" address book must be the first!
                            'the code can be adapted to search in all of them, if many...
 If olGAL.AddressEntries.count < 1 Then
    MsgBox "You must set ""Contacts"" folder as ""Outlook Address Book"", from its ""Properties""."
    nameByPhoneNo = "No Address Book coould be found..."
    Exit Function
 End If

 Set olEntry = olGAL.AddressEntries

 For Each olMember In olEntry
    If InStr(olMember.GetContact.BusinessTelephoneNumber, strPhNo) > 0 Or _
       InStr(olMember.GetContact.HomeTelephoneNumber, strPhNo) > 0 Or _
       InStr(olMember.GetContact.MobileTelephoneNumber, strPhNo) > 0 Then
           nameByPhoneNo = olMember.GetContact.fullName: Exit Function
    End If
 Next
End Function
```

The function can be adapted to also search by "Company Name" etc.

It can be tested in this way:

```
Sub testNameByPhoneNo()
    Debug.Print nameByPhoneNo("123252900") 'use it as string (between double quotes)
End Sub
```

Comment: Never loop through all items in an address book - some GAL containers can have tens of thousands of entries, and you wouldn't even be able to loop through them.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko: Yes, its speed is according to the address book number of items. In my case, it could find the match in less the two seconds. I do not know how many such items contains the OP's address book to be searched. I only played today with it, in order to find a solution and the above one worked fast enough. Of course, for my address book number of items...

Comment: This is the equivalent of creating a SELECT SQL statement without a WHERE clause. Your DBA won't be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike message store providers, most address book providers do not support arbitrary searches (only because Outlook does not use them), so on the low level most of them support simple `PR_ANR` searches, which is what `CreateRecipient` / `Resolve` use AFAIK - it is essentially "here is a string, find the best match that makes sense to you".

Some address book providers (such as GAL) expose search templates (you can see its UI in the Outlook address book if you click "Advanced Search". That functionality is available either in Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language - see [RDOAddressListSearch](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressListSearch.htm) object). Unfortunately, phone number is not one of the supported search fields for GAL - only fist/last names, department, company, city, etc. are.